# Can I check the values of XMM or YMM registers in Visual C++ breakpoint conditions?

Tags: visual-studio, masm, visual-studio-debugging, avx

I can specify the condition to be `mm0 != 0`, and it works, but for `xmm0 != 0` I get the error "no operand "!=" matches these operands". Are XMM and YMM registers not supported as variables in breakpoint conditions, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. XMM register cannot be compared directly in a breakpoint. Nor does an expression like XMM0 != XMM1 work as a breakpoint expression.

Comment: That's a shame. Is it at least possible to see packed XMM and YMM values as floats?

Comment: You could do two things .. 1. sequentially extract one of the qwords into a register and check using that register (cascade across all 2/4 using VPERMD) .. or, 2. use VTEST to get the flag and set the breakpoint using the flag value (if most significant bit can reflect your check) .. Trust this helps

Comment: @Alex: If you have a spare integer register, `vpcmpeqd xmm5, xmm0, xmm1` / `vpmovmskb r11d, xmm5` and break on `r11 != 0xffffffff` will check for bitwise (in)equality.  Or for FP compares, `vcmpeqps` / `vmovmskps` or the `pd` versions.  If you don't have a spare integer register, `vpackssdw xmm5,xmm5,xmm5` will narrow a compare result from dword to word elements, repeated in each 64-bit half.  So `movdq2q mm0, xmm5` will set you up for an MMX breakpoint on `mm0 == 0xffffffff`.  (You'll need an `emms` after this debugging code.)  This would only work in hand-written asm I guess.

Comment: Or as quasar66 says, `vptest ymm0, ymm0` will set ZF in FLAGS if all 256 bits were zero, otherwise clear it.  `vtestps` / `pd` only cares about the sign bits of dword / qword elements, so integer `vptest` is what you want to check every bit.